# Use of IsCancellationRequested property?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

What is the use of `CancellationToken`'s `IsCancellationRequested` property? Consider below code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Start.\nAgain Press enter to finish.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Task t = new Task(() =>
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task Cancel requested");
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(i++);
        }
    }, token);

    t.Start();

    // wait for input before exiting
    Console.ReadLine();
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    if(t.Status==TaskStatus.Canceled)
        Console.WriteLine("Task was cancelled");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Task completed");
}
```

I find that on rare occasions code inside `if` block doesn't run. If so what is the use of polling to see if cancellation is requested?

Comment: I suspect your diagnostics are off. It should work fine. What *exactly* do you observe in the failure case? Is it possible that there's just a delay while your output buffer catches up?

Comment: some times i dont see the output "Task Cancel requested" in the console when i hit enter the 2nd time. But it is very rare.

Comment: I suspect it's just a race condition in console output (although that's a little odd). It's clearly always going through that code, otherwise the task wouldn't stop. In the failure cases, does the program still finish?

Comment: i can always see "Task Completed" output in the window and program completes when i hit enter

Comment: In that case it's *definitely* just a diagnostic problem. There's no way the task would complete *without* noticing cancellation (leaving checked overflow aside) so it's just a matter of the console output.

Comment: hmm ok..i will test some other way and come back if i find some thing abnormal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you don't wait for the `Task` to finish. So, what can happen is this:

1. You call `Cancel()`.
2. You check `Status`, which returns `Running`.
3. Confusingly, you write “Task completed” when the `Task` is still running.
4. `Main()` completes, application exits.
5. (At this point, `IsCancellationRequested` would be checked from the background thread. But that never happens, since the application already exited.)

To fix that, add `t.Wait()` after you call `Cancel()`.

But that still won't fix your program completely. You need to tell the `Task` that it was canceled. And you do that by throwing `OperationCanceledException` that contains the `CancellationToken` (the usual way to do that is to call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`).

One issue with that is that `Wait()`ing on a `Task` that was canceled will throw an exception, so you will have to catch that.

Comment: thx for your answer can you please explain little bit what is 'At this point, IsCancellationRequested would be checked from the background thread.'

Comment: @Sat I'm not sure what's there to explain. The timing of operations on different threads is unpredictable, so this is one possible way the operations can happen.

Comment: ok. t.Wait() works. Back ground thread exits as soon as main thread does. am i right? so in my prevoius case main might have exited before background could reach Console.Write...

Comment: @Sat Yeah, application exists as soon as all foreground threads exit. And if some background threads are executing at the point, they are forcibly closed too.