# How to cancel a CancellationToken

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

I start a task, that starts other tasks and so forth. Given that tree, if any task fails the result of the whole operation is useless. I'm considering using cancellation tokens. To my surprise, the token does not have a "CancelThisToken()" method...

How can I, in possession of **only** a [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx), cancel it?

Comment: You're looking for CancellationTokenSource  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CoderDennis I dont see how i can obtain the token source given only the token...

Comment: If you don't have a `CancellationTokenSource` then you can't cancel it. The token is an object that all the threads share, this object is set by the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` method. Once done so, the `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` would be true. Until then, it will always be false. (It cannot be set directly.) If you don't have a `CancellationTokenSource`, then there is nothing that is capable of throwing the cancellation. You **require** a `CancellationTokenSource` to cancel threads like that.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

As the documentation states, you need to call the `Cancel()` method from the *token source*, not the token itself. Note the example code in the [CancellationToken Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

```c-sharp
// Define the cancellation token.
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;
...
source.Cancel();
```

> how can I, in possession of ***only*** a CancellationToken, cancel it?

**Without a reference to the source you cannot cancel the token**, this is by design.

As a flawed workaround, when given a `CancellationToken`, you can create a new instance of the token source, assign its token to the provided token, and cancel the new source:

```c-sharp
// Define the cancellation token.
CancellationTokenSource newSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
existingToken = newSource.Token;
...
newSource.Cancel();
// "existingToken" is cancelled hereafter
```

...but this will only affect downstream consumers of the token. Any entities with the token prior to updating the reference will still have the original, uncancelled token.

But do note that if *you're* creating the token to track tasks, then you *do* have the source, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Leonardo, You should first create the tokensource and then request the token from it. Look at the example code in the link I provided

Comment: This is the method I use for our backup utility at work - if any `Task` fails my results are useless as well. (The two databases, one SQL, one AS/400 DB2, are out of sync, and that's unacceptable. So I discard all data if anything fails.)

Comment: @Leonardo, If you are still confused after looking at the longer example update your question with your code and I will try to provide more information

Comment: @Leonardo You *can't* get the source when given only the token.  it is *by design* that you cannot cancel a token when all you have is that token.  It would be a broken system if it could.

Comment: @RyanS You should probably add something answering the `how can I, in possession of ONLY a CancellationToken, cancel it?` as well.

Comment: @EBrown, From my understanding and as Servy commented that is not possible and is not the way to use Cancelation Token

Comment: @RyanS I meant you should add Servy's information (or mine) to the answer.

Comment: Overriding `previouslyProvidedToken` like in the edit is a bad practice... If the source of the provided token is cancelled (on a higher level in the tree), this functionally would not react to that cancel. Passing a CancellationToken would be entirely useless in this case, so Daniel Park's answer offers a better solution.

Comment: @RyanS _"When given a Token, you can create a new instance of token source assign it's token to the provided token and cancel it"_. This is not true, you cannot assign `CancellationTokenSource.Token` property, it is readonly.

Comment: @JobaDiniz its been a while since I added this answer but I believe I meant that you could get the token from the tokensource and assign that to something else, not the other way around (which as you stated cannot be done)

Comment: Ha, that's really clever! I know it's a hack, but then again, cancelling a token without a Source calls for a hack. Good work :)

Comment: Don't forget to call `source.Dispose();` when you are done using it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource

Comment: *"When given a `CancellationToken`, you can create a new instance of the token source, assign it's token to the provided token, and cancel it."* <== Could you provide an example of this technique?

Comment: It should be noted that internal cancellation is different from external cancellation. If you want a way to cancel form within, you don't cancel using the external source. Yes, you need two cancel tokens but now you can distinguish who requested the cancel.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but "assign its token *to the provided token*" in the "flawed workaround" seems misleading - you're just overwriting the variable value holding the old token with the new one. Nothing is done to the old value of `existingToken`. Thus, the "workaround" is effectively: "ignore `existingToken` completely and just pass a new token created from your own `CancellationTokenSource`" which does not "work around" anything at all.

Answer (score 25):

As an extension of the answers provided so far, if you want to have both a `CancellationToken` instance provided to your methods, *and* cancel internally, you should examine [`CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642265(v=vs.110).aspx).
In essence this will cancel either when `cts.Cancel()` is called, or one of its supplied tokens is.

Answer (score 14):

A token gives you the right to know someone is trying to cancel something. It does not give you the right to actually signal a cancellation. Only the cancellation token source gives you that. This is by design.

Comment: Perhaps address the question directly? I take it the answer is "You can't"(?)

Answer (score 4):

Spawn `CancellationToken` instances from a `CancellationTokenSource` instance and call `Cancel` on the CTS instance.

Example: *[Cancel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource_Cancel)*

There's also a way to gracefully cancel threads without them firing exceptions. Just check the CT for `IsCancellationRequested` and handle the case yourself.

More information: *[Use of IsCancellationRequested property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038529/use-of-iscancellationrequested-property)*

Comment: Then as you are being provided one you are in control of the cancellation. You can either keep tabs on IsCancellationRequested or rely on the framework throwing an exception on your thread to forcibly do so.

Answer (score -1):

Several answers here has stated that it is considered a hack and anti-pattern to on-demand cancel a cancellation token without using the original CancellationTokenSource. If you still want to do this and not throw an exception like using a combination of `IsCancellationRequested` and `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` method, you can create an extension method to on-demand cancel a cancellation token.

```
public static class CancellationTokenExtensions
{    
    public static void ForceCancel(ref this CancellationToken cancellationToken, 
    Func<bool>? condition = null)
    {
        if (condition == null || condition.Invoke())
        {
            var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(
            cancellationToken);
            cancellationToken = cts.Token;
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

We use ref here since CancellationToken is a struct and want to modify the token object and must take care here since we pass a struct by value otherwise into the extension method. This is supported since C# 7.3.

If you use older C#,  return the CancellationToken object and overwrite the cancellation token you passed in (probably not use this argument then since you overwrite it anyways).

Sample source code in a demo app in a Pluralsight course I am looking at right now shows how I added usage of this method inside a MVC controller action. Ignore much of the surrounding code here, point is that we can now easily cancel on demand a cancellation token. I have tested the code in Swagger API that display the controller and tested that it works.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductModel>> Get(CancellationToken cancelToken, 
    string category = "all")
    {
        //cancelToken.ForceCancel();
        cancelToken.ForceCancel(() => category == "kayak");

        using (_logger.BeginScope("ScopeCat: {ScopeCat}", category))
        {     
            _logger.LogInformation( "Getting products in API.");
            return await _productLogic.GetProductsForCategoryAsync(cancelToken, 
            category);
        }
    }
```

We can skip the condition argument if we want to, then the cancellation token will be canceled, as soon as possible and throw an OperationCancelled exception in your downstream code. Remember to pass the updated token downwards, if you use C# 7.3 or newer, the object is updated automatically for you using this code. You will see that `IsCancellationRequested` is true, when you inspect the updated token (which now is a new struct).

Should you also keep track of the newly instantiated CancellationTokenSource inside the cts variable in the method ? This could also be an option, letting the extension method return `CancellationTokenSource` you created here and save this to a var in the calling code. That object is a class by the way.

Comment: I don't get the point of all this complexity and indirection. I you want to throw an exception in case the `category` is `"kayak"`, then you can just do `if (category == "kayak") throw new OperationCanceledException();`.

Comment: Your comment agrees with what is suggested in the bottom of this article  : 
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3674845/how-to-use-cancellation-tokens-in-aspnet-core-7.html

I still keep my answer as an example how to cancel a cancellationtoken programatically  instead of throwing an OperationCanceledException, which would cancel the original cancellation token and I agree it is a better approach. Still the example shows how you could do it alternatively. Though I will not suggest it as it increases complexity.

Comment: A `CancellationToken` can only be canceled by its parent `CancellationTokenSource`. If you don't have access to the parent CTS, you can't cancel the token. Your answer shows a complicated way to create a new CTS, and throw an `OperationCanceledException` related with its token, which is a different token than the original token. The original token remains non-canceled. The fact that the new CTS is connected with the original token is irrelevant. Being connected doesn't mean "it's the same".