# Is the correct way to cancel a cancellation token used in a task?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have code that creates a cancellation token

```
public partial class CardsTabViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   public CancellationTokenSource cts;

public async Task OnAppearing()
{
   cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // << runs as part of OnAppearing()
```

Code that uses it:

```
await GetCards(cts.Token);


public async Task GetCards(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        App.viewablePhrases = App.DB.GetViewablePhrases(Settings.Mode, Settings.Pts);
        await CheckAvailability();
    }
}
```

and code that later cancels this Cancellation Token if the user moves away from the screen where the code above is running:

```
public void OnDisappearing()
{
   cts.Cancel();
```

Regarding cancellation, is this the correct way to cancel the token when it's being used in a Task?

In particular I checked this question:

[Use of IsCancellationRequested property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038529/use-of-iscancellationrequested-property)

and it's making me think that I am not doing the cancel the correct way or perhaps in a way that can cause an exception.

Also, in this case after I have cancelled then should I be doing a cts.Dispose()?

Comment: Normally, use the Cancel method to communicate a request for cancellation and then use Dispose method to release the memory. You could check the sample in link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` is a valid way to start cancellation.

Polling `ct.IsCancellationRequested` avoids throwing `OperationCanceledException`. 
Because its polling, it requires an iteration of the loop to complete before it will respond to the cancellation request.

If `GetViewablePhrases()` and `CheckAvailability()` can be modified to accept a `CancellationToken`, this may make cancellation faster to respond, at the cost of having `OperationCanceledException` thrown.

"should I be doing a cts.Dispose()?" is not that straightforward...

> "Always dispose IDisposables ASAP"

Is more of a guideline than a rule.
`Task` itself is disposable, yet hardly ever directly disposed in code.

There are cases (when `WaitHandle` or cancellation callback handlers are used) where disposing `cts` would free a resource / remove a GC root which otherwise would only be freed by a Finalizer.
These don't apply to your code as it stands but may in future.

Adding a call to `Dispose` after cancelling would guarantee that these resources are freed promptly in future versions of the code.

However, you'd have to either wait for the code that uses `cts` to finish before calling dispose, or modify the code to deal with `ObjectDisposedException` from use of `cts` (or its token) after disposal.

Comment: "hook up OnDisappearing to dispose cts"  Seems like a very bad idea, because, it's still in use inside another task.  Particularly if someone does later change the design (modify the subtasks to accept a `CancellationToken` parameter), you could be disposing the `WaitHandle` while another thread is actively waiting on it :(

Comment: In particular, because you made the claim that "cancel performs the same cleanup as dispose", it would be pointless to call `Dispose` from `OnDisappearing`.

Comment: Whoops, I missed that the code in the answer already calls `Cancel`...

Comment: Have deleted the claim about cancel doing the same cleanup (which I'd read elsewhere on s.o.), as far as I can tell the only cleanup `Cancel` does is the internal timer (if used).

Answer (score 4):

In general I see a fair use of Cancel Token in your code, but according the Task Async Pattern your code could be not cancelling immediately.

```
while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
{
   App.viewablePhrases = App.DB.GetViewablePhrases(Settings.Mode, Settings.Pts);
   await CheckAvailability();   //Your Code could be blocked here, unable to cancel
}
```

For responding right away, the blocking code also should be cancelled

```
await CheckAvailability(ct);   //Your blocking code in the loop also should be stoped
```

It is up to you if you must Dispose, if there are many memory resources been reserved in the interrupted code, you should do it.

Comment: And indeed this would also apply to the call to GetViewablePhrases - ideally this would be an async call as well and take in a cancellation token as an option.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to take a look on one of the .net classes to fully understand how to handle wait methods with CanncelationToken, I picked up SeamaphoreSlim.cs

```
    public bool Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CheckDispose();

        // Validate input
        if (millisecondsTimeout < -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                "totalMilliSeconds", millisecondsTimeout, GetResourceString("SemaphoreSlim_Wait_TimeoutWrong"));
        }

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        uint startTime = 0;
        if (millisecondsTimeout != Timeout.Infinite && millisecondsTimeout > 0)
        {
            startTime = TimeoutHelper.GetTime();
        }

        bool waitSuccessful = false;
        Task<bool> asyncWaitTask = null;
        bool lockTaken = false;

        //Register for cancellation outside of the main lock.
        //NOTE: Register/deregister inside the lock can deadlock as different lock acquisition orders could
        //      occur for (1)this.m_lockObj and (2)cts.internalLock
        CancellationTokenRegistration cancellationTokenRegistration = cancellationToken.InternalRegisterWithoutEC(s_cancellationTokenCanceledEventHandler, this);
        try
        {
            // Perf: first spin wait for the count to be positive, but only up to the first planned yield.
            //       This additional amount of spinwaiting in addition
            //       to Monitor.Enter()’s spinwaiting has shown measurable perf gains in test scenarios.
            //
            SpinWait spin = new SpinWait();
            while (m_currentCount == 0 && !spin.NextSpinWillYield)
            {
                spin.SpinOnce();
            }
            // entering the lock and incrementing waiters must not suffer a thread-abort, else we cannot
            // clean up m_waitCount correctly, which may lead to deadlock due to non-woken waiters.
            try { }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Enter(m_lockObj, ref lockTaken);
                if (lockTaken)
                {
                    m_waitCount++;
                }
            }

            // If there are any async waiters, for fairness we'll get in line behind
            // then by translating our synchronous wait into an asynchronous one that we 
            // then block on (once we've released the lock).
            if (m_asyncHead != null)
            {
                Contract.Assert(m_asyncTail != null, "tail should not be null if head isn't");
                asyncWaitTask = WaitAsync(millisecondsTimeout, cancellationToken);
            }
                // There are no async waiters, so we can proceed with normal synchronous waiting.
            else
            {
                // If the count > 0 we are good to move on.
                // If not, then wait if we were given allowed some wait duration

                OperationCanceledException oce = null;

                if (m_currentCount == 0)
                {
                    if (millisecondsTimeout == 0)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Prepare for the main wait...
                    // wait until the count become greater than zero or the timeout is expired
                    try
                    {
                        waitSuccessful = WaitUntilCountOrTimeout(millisecondsTimeout, startTime, cancellationToken);
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException e) { oce = e; }
                }

                // Now try to acquire.  We prioritize acquisition over cancellation/timeout so that we don't
                // lose any counts when there are asynchronous waiters in the mix.  Asynchronous waiters
                // defer to synchronous waiters in priority, which means that if it's possible an asynchronous
                // waiter didn't get released because a synchronous waiter was present, we need to ensure
                // that synchronous waiter succeeds so that they have a chance to release.
                Contract.Assert(!waitSuccessful || m_currentCount > 0, 
                    "If the wait was successful, there should be count available.");
                if (m_currentCount > 0)
                {
                    waitSuccessful = true;
                    m_currentCount--;
                }
                else if (oce != null)
                {
                    throw oce;
                }

                // Exposing wait handle which is lazily initialized if needed
                if (m_waitHandle != null && m_currentCount == 0)
                {
                    m_waitHandle.Reset();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Release the lock
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                m_waitCount--;
                Monitor.Exit(m_lockObj);
            }

            // Unregister the cancellation callback.
            cancellationTokenRegistration.Dispose();
        }

        // If we had to fall back to asynchronous waiting, block on it
        // here now that we've released the lock, and return its
        // result when available.  Otherwise, this was a synchronous
        // wait, and whether we successfully acquired the semaphore is
        // stored in waitSuccessful.

        return (asyncWaitTask != null) ? asyncWaitTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult() : waitSuccessful;
    }
```

You can also view the whole class here, https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs,6095d9030263f169