# Limit the number of cores: new Task will block until core free from other tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have code like this:

```
var listAction = new List<Task>();
...

foreach (var symbol in chunk)
{
    listAction.Add(Task.Run(() => DoBooster(symbol, ...)));
}

int failed = 0;
Task t = Task.WhenAll(listAction);
try
{
    t.Wait();
}
catch { }

if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
{
    Console.WriteLine("All Boosters succeeded.");
}
else if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Booster failed", failed);
}
```

The problem is, I want to limit the number of `tasks` that run simultaneously. Ideally, I would like to say (this doesn't exist I am just saying what I would like)

```
maxConcurrentTasks = 4;
```

I would still like to loop as above and keep adding `tasks` indefinitely, but I want `tasks` to block if `maxConcurrentTasks` is exceeded EVEN IF THERE AREA AVAILABLE cores, and when the number of tasks is below `maxConcurrentTasks`, any pending `tasks` are started.

So, if there are 16 symbols, only 4 are being processed at a time. When one is processed, another task that is blocking starts up but the number of running tasks never exceeds `maxConcurrentTasks`, until the final symbol is processed.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75112527/how-can-i-use-parallel-tasks-and-make-them-not-waiting-each-other?noredirect=1#comment132550179_75112527

Comment: Here's another dupe-ish answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36564596/14357

Comment: Thaks that's helpful. I know I can queue the tasks myself, but often with these libraries there is already a built in way to do this....

Comment: In essense, I need to throttle myself

Comment: @Ivan Yes, being conservative about what you throw at the ThreadPool is definitely a good idea.

Comment: The moment you need to introduce an arbitrary throttle AND independent execution based on that throttle, you're going to need to write something yourself. I'm not aware of anything built-in that solves it for you, when taking async into account. Luckily you can build on top of queues and channels to do so, but you'll have to design the conditions carefully.

Comment: @Ivan `Parallel.ForEach` and `Parallel.ForEachAsync` ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-parallel-foreachasync-1(system-collections-generic-iasyncenumerable((-0))-system-threading-tasks-paralleloptions-system-func((-0-system-threading-cancellationtoken-system-threading-tasks-valuetask))))) accept a [`ParallelOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions?view=net-7.0) as their second (?) parameter. Here you can set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4`.